# Using Google sign in api - manage users permission

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin

I understand that I can use Google Sign in button and grant access to my website only to users from my domain (using metadata tag).

My question is, once a user is logged in can I control the pages that he/she sees. For example I want some users to be admins but other users to be regular users. Each user 'type' will have access to different set of pages.

Thanks,
Shay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's sign-in API can only authenticate users, it can't manage authorizations. For that you'll need to either use a cloud service like Cognito (which supports Google sign-in as a federated login provider for its own temporarily-generated identity) or write your own server-side access manager that associates the sign-in token with specific permissions, and then handles the authorization of user requests.